# validate field at run time on field change

Tags: serenity-platform

I need to know if the phone to register already exists in the bank before clicking Save or Update.
I need to check this restriction when changing the field.
In other words, when leaving the Celular field, if it exists in the bank, it will already notify me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGJiQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create an endpoint for checking phone number on db. Then add validation rule with calling this service.
Sample of adding validation is [here](https://github.com/serenity-is/Serene/blob/daefd17cdf4713fce40d5145bde35b5a250dd26d/Serene/Serene.Core/Modules/Administration/User/UserDialog.ts#L17).